# MariaDB / MySQL INSERT INTO / ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in Python

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I’m trying to INSERT INTO / ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE taking the values from one table and inserting into another. I have the following Python code.

```
try:
    cursor.execute("SELECT LocationId, ProviderId FROM CQCLocationDetailsUpdates")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        maria_cnxn.execute('INSERT INTO CQCLocationDetailsUpdates2 (LocationId, ProviderId) VALUES (%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ProviderId = VALUES(%s)', row)
        mariadb_connection.commit()

except TypeError as error:
    print(error)
    mariadb_connection.rollback()
```

If I change this script just to `INSERT INTO` it work fine, the problem seems to be when I add the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. What do I have wrong? `LocationId` is the `PRIMARY KEY`

I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/waynes/PycharmProjects/DRS_Dev/CQC_Locations_Update_MariaDB.py", line 228, in <module>
    maria_cnxn.execute('INSERT INTO CQCLocationDetailsUpdates2 (LocationId, ProviderId) VALUES (%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ProviderId = VALUES(%s)', row)
  File "C:\Users\waynes\PycharmProjects\DRS_Dev\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 548, in execute
    stmt = RE_PY_PARAM.sub(psub, stmt)
  File "C:\Users\waynes\PycharmProjects\DRS_Dev\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 79, in __call__
    "Not enough parameters for the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement
```

Comment: Can you try that with the parameters being `(*row, row[-1])` instead of `row` in the `execute` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is because row is a 2 element tuple and your SQL statement requires three `%s` vars.

It is however possible to use an [INSERT .. SELECT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/insert-select/) like:

```
maria_cnxn.execute('INSERT INTO CQCLocationDetailsUpdates2 (LocationId, 
 ProviderId)
 SELECT LocationId, ProviderId
 FROM CQCLocationDetailsUpdates orig
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CQCLocationDetailsUpdates2.ProviderID = orig.ProviderID')
```

Whenever you end up doing a loop around a SQL statement you should look to see if there is a SQL way of doing this.